# Unable to ALTER TABLE inside CASE WHEN within Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a fairly simple Stored Procedure on MySQL, but it keeps throwing errors.

There are additional `WHEN` conditions, but I've removed them here to keep it simple, and this simpler version doesn't work either.  I get `SQL Error 1064 in Statement #2: You have an error in your SQL Syntax... near ELSE CALL finance.sprProce...`.

The `finance.spProcessTrans_AddToLogs` are fine, I use the exact syntax in a number of other SPs.  The code that is processed between the `WHEN`s is fine as I've tested it separately.

Version: Windows/MySQL 8.0.12 Community

Where am I going wrong?  Should I be able to do this ALTER TABLE within a CASE WHEN?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS finance.spProcessIndex;

CREATE PROCEDURE finance.spProcessIndex(
    IN tblName VARCHAR(50),
    IN actDesc VARCHAR(50)
    )
    BEGIN

    SET tblName = IFNULL(tblName, 'ERROR');     
    SET actDesc = IFNULL(actDesc, 'ERROR');     

    CASE
    WHEN actDesc='CREATE' THEN
        CASE
        WHEN tblName='tbl_transactions' THEN
            ALTER TABLE tbl_transactions 
                MODIFY TransactionID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                ADD INDEX IDX_ProcessTrans_A (CustomerRef, TransMonth, Product, TransValue, RowReference, TransactionID,ProdInCust_Mnth_Same_SameProd_LowerVal),
                ADD INDEX IDX_tbl_transactions_product (Product(25)),
                ADD INDEX IDX_tbl_transactions_prodval (Product, TransValue);
        ELSE
            ALTER TABLE tbl_transactions_tmp_worker_aa 
                MODIFY TransactionID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                ADD INDEX IDX_ProcessTrans_A (CustomerRef, TransMonth, Product, TransValue, RowReference, TransactionID,ProdInCust_Mnth_Same_SameProd_LowerVal),
                ADD INDEX IDX_tbl_transactions_product (Product(25)),
                ADD INDEX IDX_tbl_transactions_prodval (Product, TransValue);
        END;
    ELSE
        CALL finance.spProcessTrans_AddToLogs('spProcessIndex','BREAKPOINT','ERROR: Bad ACTION',CONCAT('A bad ACTION was specified {',actDesc,'}'));
    END;

    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

-- DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS finance.spProcessIndex;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS finance.spProcessIndex//
.
.
.
CASE
  WHEN actDesc='CREATE' THEN
.
.
.
  CASE
    WHEN tblName='tbl_transactions' THEN
  .
  .
  .
  END CASE;
END CASE;
.
.
.

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't even consider it should be END CASE, as I've used just END in other SPs and it's been fine.  Is there a set scenario when you should(n't) use END (CASE)?  I've checked the documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html but still unsure.

Comment: @aSystemOverload: **[CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression**, differs from the **[CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) statement**, it is terminated with `END` instead of `END CASE`.